# Connect to a grpc Server running in go enabled in tls from a nodejs grpc client

Tags: node.js, go, grpc

I have a grpc server written in go which is running in tls mode.

**If I want to connect to the server from a nodejs client without verifying server's certificate chain and host name. How do I achieve that?**
(This is done by setting the InsecureSkipVerify Flag to true in tls Config in golang)

Default way to connect to a grpc server (not enabled in tls) is by using grpc.credentials.createInsecure() . but when I enable the server in tls mode and use grpc.credentials.createSsl() it gives me  the following error log:

> E1207 20:47:12.228100000 123145571782656 handshake.c:128] Security
>   handshake failed:
>   {"created":"@1481123832.228090000","description":"Handshake
>   failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":264,"tsi_code":10,"tsi_error":"TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE"}

How do I get rid of this error and connect to the tls enabled grpc server without giving any certificates in the nodejs client??

Comment: Try setting `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` before you make the request.

Comment: We have already tried that @dan. But it's still not working.

Comment: is there any update on this ? is there any workaround to connect to a tls enabled grpc server from nodejs client using certificates

Comment: No.. not yet. i am still waiting for the right answer @Praful